# How to use semanage to get persist specific file types recursively

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos, selinux

I'm currently running Centos 7 and configuring SELinux enabled, currently I configure my apache docroot under the /home/user/public_html and files/folders show the context label:

```
-rw-r--r--. user apache system_u:object_r:httpd_user_content_t:s0 readme.html
-rw-r--r--. user apache system_u:object_r:httpd_user_content_t:s0 wp-activate.php
drwxrwxr-x. user apache system_u:object_r:httpd_user_content_t:s0 wp-admin
-rw-r--r--. user apache system_u:object_r:httpd_user_content_t:s0 wp-blog-header.php
-rw-r--r--. user apache system_u:object_r:httpd_user_content_t:s0 wp-comments-post.php
-rw-r--r--. user apache system_u:object_r:httpd_user_content_t:s0 wp-config-sample.php
drwxrwxr-x. user apache system_u:object_r:httpd_user_content_t:s0 wp-content
-rw-r--r--. user apache system_u:object_r:httpd_user_content_t:s0 wp-cron.php
drwxrwxr-x. user apache system_u:object_r:httpd_user_content_t:s0 wp-includes
-rw-r--r--. user apache system_u:object_r:httpd_user_content_t:s0 wp-links-opml.php
-rw-r--r--. user apache system_u:object_r:httpd_user_content_t:s0 wp-load.php
-rw-r--r--. user apache system_u:object_r:httpd_user_content_t:s0 wp-login.php
-rw-r--r--. user apache system_u:object_r:httpd_user_content_t:s0 wp-mail.php
-rw-r--r--. user apache system_u:object_r:httpd_user_content_t:s0 wp-settings.php
-rw-r--r--. user apache system_u:object_r:httpd_user_content_t:s0 wp-signup.php
-rw-r--r--. user apache system_u:object_r:httpd_user_content_t:s0 wp-trackback.php
-rw-r--r--. user apache system_u:object_r:httpd_user_content_t:s0 xmlrpc.php
```

I want to assign and change current context label `httpd_user_content_t` to `httpd_user_script_exec_t` recursively and apply only for all .php file types under public_html/. I already tried below code but the context still not changed:

```
# sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_user_script_exec_t "/home/user/public_html/.*\.php"
# sudo restorecon -Rv public_html
# ls -Z
    -rw-r--r--. user apache system_u:object_r:httpd_user_content_t:s0 readme.html
    -rw-r--r--. user apache system_u:object_r:httpd_user_content_t:s0 wp-activate.php
    drwxrwxr-x. user apache system_u:object_r:httpd_user_content_t:s0 wp-admin
    -rw-r--r--. user apache system_u:object_r:httpd_user_content_t:s0 wp-blog-header.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the brackets to tell SELinux that you want to use a regular expression. Try it like that:

```
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_user_script_exec_t "/home/user/public_html/(.*\.php)"
```